# Visual Studio 2013 installation giving an error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install VS2013 but as my `C`drive is full i am trying to install on my `H` drive which has 13GB of free space.

But while installing Setup window is highlighting an option that `all drives need 9GB free space`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you select a different drive, Visual Studio will still install some components to your system drive. Things like shared packages and libraries. You will need to free up space on your C drive to install Visual Studio.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2012/03/07/why-visual-studio-11-requires-space-on-the-system-drive.aspx

Comment: Should do, I don't know exactly how much it needs though.